# How to replace a Materialize Select with Text-Input dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I'm trying to elicit a change from a Materialize `select` to a `text[input]`  of input when the user clicks on `Other`

I've tried using `.replaceWith()`, `instance.destroy();`, and `$(this).remove()` all to no avail.

HTML:

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<h5>Materialize select</h5>


<div class="row">
 <div class="input-field col s12">
   <i class="material-icons prefix">device_hub</i>
   <select id="mySelect" class="change_select_to_text_on_other">
     <option value=""  selected>Choose "Other" to trigger!</option>
     <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     <option value="other">Other</option>
   </select>
    <!--This is what I would like replace the select option with when other is clicked!:
    <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
    <label for="first_name">Make your own selection!</label-->
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $select1 = $('#mySelect');

$select1.material_select();
$select1.on('change', function (e) {
    if(e.target.value == 'other'){
    $( this ).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
    var instance = M.FormSelect.getInstance($(this));
    instance.destroy();
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brandon007pillay/nj9ypvg7/)

When the user clicks on other option the select gets replaced with a text input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this close to what you want? I used a newer version of materialize.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js

So I used `$select1.formSelect();` instead of `$select1.material_select();`

The complete code:

```
$(function () {
    var $select1 = $('#mySelect');

    $select1.formSelect();
    $select1.on('change', function (e) {

        if (e.target.value == 'other') {
            $(this).replaceWith(`<input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="first_name">Make your own selection!</label>`);
            $( ".select-dropdown.dropdown-trigger" ).remove();
            $( ".caret" ).remove();

        }
    });
})
```